# Does F# have multi-way if?

Tags: haskell, if-statement, f#, pattern-matching

Is there a way to refactor this:

```
let collide (b1 : Box) (b2 : Box) =
  if   bottom b1 > top b2
  then false
  else if   top b1 < bottom b2
       then false
       else if   right b1 < left b2
            then false
            else if   left b1 > right b2
                 then false
                 else true
```

in a more readable way than this:

```
let collide (b1 : Box) (b2 : Box) =
  match () with
  | _ when bottom b1 > top    b2 -> false
  | _ when top    b1 < bottom b2 -> false
  | _ when right  b1 < left   b2 -> false
  | _ when left   b1 > right  b2 -> false
  | _                            -> true
```

?

I am thinking of something similar to multi-way if-expressions in from GHC 7.6.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.1/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#multi-way-if .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let collide (b1 : Box) (b2 : Box) = 
    if   bottom b1 > top b2 then false 
    elif top b1 < bottom b2 then false 
    elif right b1 < left b2 then false 
    elif left b1 > right b2 then false 
    else true
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use `||` -

```
not (bottom b1>topb2 || top b1<bottom b2 || right b1<left b2 || left b1>right b2)
```

Comment: i just can't can't grasp this :) is this even equivalent to the original without a negation added in somewhere?

Comment: @John: In order for your expression to yield result equivalent to the original snippet you should invert all conditions: `bottom b1<=top b2 && ...`

Comment: @GeneBelitski what about negating the whole expression `not (bottom ... && .... && ........)`?

Comment: @Cetin: `not` really :), the equivalent of `(not a)&&(not b)` is `not(a||b)`

Comment: I think what I have now is correct - but this shows why I should think more before writing

Answer (score 4):

Complementing [Brian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12594146/396458), it's also worth pointing out that `elif` is just sugar for `else if`. i.e. you can reformat your original  code so that it isn't all that bad:

```
let collide (b1 : Box) (b2 : Box) =
    if bottom b1 > top b2 then false
    else if top b1 < bottom b2 then false
    else if right b1 < left b2 then false
    else if left b1 > right b2 then false
    else true
```